# Laravel Passport doesn't return bearer token

Tags: laravel, web-services, token, laravel-passport

I've used `Laravel` `Passport` to create a `brearer token` in my `web service`. This is my code:

```
$bearerToken = $this->tokenGenerate($request->username, $request->pass);

return $bearerToken;
```

And `tokenGenerate` function is as below:

```
public function tokenGenerate($username, $password)
    {
        $client   = new GuzzleClient();
        $response = $client->request('POST', env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token', [

            RequestOptions::JSON => [
                "username"       => $username,
                "password"       => $password,
                "grant_type"     => "password",
                "client_id"      => 7,
                "client_secret"  => "avTabhOqPCsq81q1aYqnLa9HmAWLE3Gz0Ey78kds",
                "theNewProvider" => "subscribers",
                'scope' => '*',
            ]
        ]);

        return $response;

    }
```

It doesn't work properly and it just returns **the passed username** when I test my `web service` in `Postman`.

When I change `return $response` to `dd($response)`, this is the result:

```
Response {#808
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:6 [
    "Date" => array:1 [
      0 => "Sun, 13 Jan 2019 10:09:48 GMT"
    ]
    "Server" => array:1 [
      0 => "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)"
    ]
    "X-Powered-By" => array:1 [
      0 => "PHP/7.2.13"
    ]
    "Content-Length" => array:1 [
      0 => "11"
    ]
    "Connection" => array:1 [
      0 => "close"
    ]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [
      0 => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:6 [
    "date" => "Date"
    "server" => "Server"
    "x-powered-by" => "X-Powered-By"
    "content-length" => "Content-Length"
    "connection" => "Connection"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#823
    -stream: stream resource @636
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling your own api internally?  What you want to return is $response->getBody()... you are not using Guzzle right..

Comment: The first part is another function that is calling tokenGenerate function and contains some other functionalities that I haven't mentioned here. I changed my code as you said but again it returned $username.

Comment: Have hou checked your middlewares?

Comment: What should I do exactly?

Comment: Okay - in the above code, do a dd($response) in stead of returninh; that will give you option to see if that is correct.  If that outputs what you expect, it’s probably some middleware doing crazy stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it and inform you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186619/discussion-between-hoda-kh-and-david-heremans).